# Field extensions: compute the degree of an extension.

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field

I'm stuck with this problem.

Let $F\subseteq E$ and $\gamma\in E$ is trascendental over $F$. Let $m$ be a positive integer.

> Show that $[F(\gamma):F(\gamma^{m})]=m$, where $[\quad:\quad]$ is the degree of the extension.

So far, I've tried this:
We know that 
$p(x)=x^{m}-\gamma^{m}\in F(\gamma^{m})[x]$, and $p(\gamma)=0$, so $[F(\gamma):F(\gamma^{m})]\leq m$. I tried to exhibit a set of l.i. vectors of $F(\gamma)$ over $F(\gamma^{m})$. But I failed. Any idea?

Comment: Doesn't the generalized Eisentein's criterion give you that $p$ is irreducible?

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eisenstein's_criterion#Generalization

Comment: The Eisentein's criterion needs that the polynomial over Z, but we don´t know that.

Comment: Please go through the link above for the generalization. I think it will help.

Comment: Thanks, voldemort. I'm thinking how I can use it.

Comment: voldemort, I understand the theorem, thanks! but we can´t use so far that generalization.

Answer (score 3):

$1,\gamma, \ldots , \gamma^{m-1}$ are independent over $F(\gamma^{m})$

Comment: I tried that, but when we write the linear combination. It's a tiresome expression, when we tried to use the fact that $\gamma$ is trascendental and write the linear combination as a polynomial in $(F(\gamma^{m}))[x]$

Comment: I think the key point is that none of the coefficients can cancel since the exponents have different residues mod $m$. This the polynomial in $\gamma$ is non zero.

Comment: @Aleph: $\;\{1,\gamma,...,\gamma^{m-1}\}\;$ not lin. ind. $\;\implies\;\exists\;$ non-zero $\;f(x)\in F(\gamma^m)[x]\;$ s.t. $\;f(\gamma)=0\;$ , but this last expression gives us that $\;\gamma\;$ is algebraic over $\;F\;$ (why?), **unless** $\;f(x)\;$ is the zero polynomial, so... Anyway, Eisenstein's Criterion is way easier, I believe.

Comment: Perfect!!! Thanks, Timbuc. I forgot to use contradiction! Bad